# Data type for Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

For a  data type of a binary tree you can write something like this:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

So if I do want to include trees, with Nodes having more than just two children, how could the data type possibly look like?

Comment: The children can be stored. In a list. They are sometimes called "rose trees": http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Tree.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either have a *fixed* branching factor:

```
data BinaryTree a  = BTNil 
                   | BTNode a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)

data TernaryTree a = TTNil
                   | TTNode a (TernaryTree a) (TernaryTree a) (TernaryTree a)

data QuadTree a    = QTNil
                   | QTNode a (QuadTree a) (QuadTree a) (QuadTree a) (QuadTree a)

-- etc
```

(Note that `QuadTree` isn't a great name for a general tree with a branching factor of 4, since there is a [specific data structure with that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).)

or you can simply use a *rose tree*, which stores an arbitrary list of children at each node.

```
data RoseTree a = RTNil | RTNode a [RoseTree a]
```

There is some duplication here, as `RTNil` is *only* needed to store an explicit empty tree. Leaf nodes are just `RTNode a []`. (Consider what difference, if any, you would assign to the values `RTNode 3 []`, `RTNode 3 [RTNil]`, `RTNode 3 [RTNil, RTNil]`, etc.)

Answer (score 17):

A lesser known technique is [**Left-child right-sibling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree) where you can use the *exact same* type to encode trees with more than two children per node:

[image: left-child-right-sibiling]

```
data Tree a
  = Nil
  | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) -- value, left child, right sibling
```

The alternative `[Tree a]` does *not* have a performance advantage, since Haskell lists are linked lists.